# C pthread programming(counting prime numbers) using mutex_lock, cond_wait

Tags: c, pthreads

i want to make a programme that counts the number of prime between certain numbers.
i made a circular queue to save prime numbers.
so basically, 2 threads find prime numbers and enqueue in the circular queue, and
1 thread takes out the prime numbers and count them.
from my code, get_prime() and get_prime2() does the enqueue thing and consumer() does the taking out thing.
the problem is, it doesn't count the prime number correctly. i think, in progress, even if the queue is full, one of the enqueueing thread tries to put the prime number in the queue so that prime number isn't put in the queue and it's missed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <math.h>

//queue size
#define QUEUESIZE 1

//a node in a queue
typedef struct queue{
    int element[QUEUESIZE+1];
    int front;
    int rear;
    int count;
}queue;

//make a queue
queue q;

pthread_mutex_t mutex_lock;
pthread_cond_t p_cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t c_cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

//prime count
int count=0;

//prototype
void init_queue(queue *q);
int enqueue(queue *q, int x);
int dequeue(queue *q);
int q_empty(queue *q);
int q_full(queue *q);
void *get_prime();
void *get_prime2();
void *consumer();

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    pthread_t p_thread[2]; //producer thread
    pthread_t c_thread;  //consumer thread
    int status;

    init_queue(&q);

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex_lock, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&p_cond, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&c_cond, NULL);
    pthread_create(&p_thread[0], NULL, get_prime, (void*)NULL);
    pthread_create(&p_thread[1], NULL, get_prime2, (void*)NULL);
    pthread_create(&c_thread, NULL, consumer, (void*)NULL);
    pthread_join(p_thread[0], (void **)&status);
    pthread_join(p_thread[1], (void **)&status);
    pthread_join(c_thread, (void **)&status);

    printf("\nThe number of prime numbers between 1~100000: %d\n", count);

    return 0;
}

//queue initialization
void init_queue(queue *q)
{
    q->front = 0;
    q->rear = QUEUESIZE-1;
    q->count = 0;
}

int enqueue(queue *q, int x)
{
    if(q_full(q))
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        q->rear = (q->rear+1) % QUEUESIZE;
        q->element[q->rear] = x;
        q->count = q->count + 1;
        return 0;
    }
}

int dequeue(queue *q)
{
int x;

if(q_empty(q))
{
    return -1;
}
else
{
    x = q->element[q->front];
    q->front = (q->front+1) % QUEUESIZE;
    q->count = q->count - 1;
}

return x;
}

int q_empty(queue *q)
{
if(q->count <= 0)
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
}

int q_full(queue *q)
{
if(q->count >=QUEUESIZE)
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
}

void *get_prime()
{
int i, j; //loop counter
int temp = 0;

for(i=2; i<50; i++)
{
    for(j=2; j<=sqrt(i); j++)
    {
        if(i%j==0){
            temp++;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(temp==0)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_lock);

        if(enqueue(&q, i)==-1) //queue full condition
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&p_cond, &mutex_lock);
            enqueue(&q, i);
            printf("%d\t", i);
        }
        else
            printf("%d\t", i);
        pthread_cond_signal(&c_cond);

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_lock);
    }
    temp=0;
}
}
void *get_prime2()
{
int i, j; //loop counter
int temp = 0;

for(i=50; i<100; i++)
{
    for(j=2; j<=sqrt(i); j++)
    {
        if(i%j==0){
            temp++;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(temp==0)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_lock);

        if(enqueue(&q, i)==-1) //queue full condition
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&p_cond, &mutex_lock);
            enqueue(&q, i);
            printf("%d\t", i);
        }
        else
            printf("%d\t", i);
        pthread_cond_signal(&c_cond);

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_lock);
    }
    temp=0;
}
}

void *consumer()
{
int isempty;

while(1)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_lock);
    isempty = dequeue(&q);

    if(isempty != -1){
        count++;
    }
    else
        pthread_cond_wait(&c_cond, &mutex_lock);
    pthread_cond_signal(&p_cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_lock);


    }
}
```

Comment: why do you empty the queue? If a number has no dividers among all primes less than or equal to square root of the number then it's a prime number.

Comment: i know, but i wanted to see how the pthread goes, so rather than just counting the number in get_prime(), i empty the queue to count

Comment: Unless you're doing this to learn, you shouldn't be doing it at all, because there is an extremely fast open-source C++ library that will do it for you: https://code.google.com/p/primesieve/

Comment: You're bitten by "Some implementations, particularly on a multi-processor, may  sometimes cause  multiple  threads to wake up when the condition variable is signaled simultaneously on different processors.", as stated in `pthread_cond_wait`'s man page. Sometimes both producers write to the queue but only one gets through to the consumer.

Comment: thanks guys i solved the problem, the problem was in get_prime(). i only checked once if the queue is full when the enqueue is done. After pthread_cond_wait(), i enqueued again but queue could be full again if the other get_prime2() thread runs enqueue first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so this is my new corrected code, thanks

```
void *get_prime2()
{
    int i, j; //loop counter
    int temp = 0;

    for(i=50000; i<100000; i++)
    {
        for(j=2; j<=sqrt(i); j++)
        {
            if(i%j==0){
                temp++;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(temp==0)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_lock);

            while(1)
            {
                if(enqueue(&q, i) == -1)
                    pthread_cond_wait(&p_cond, &mutex_lock);
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            pthread_cond_signal(&c_cond);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_lock);
        }
        temp=0;
    }
}

void *consumer()
{
    int isempty;

    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_lock);
        isempty = dequeue(&q);

        if(isempty != -1){
            count++;
        } else {
            pthread_cond_wait(&c_cond, &mutex_lock);
        }

        pthread_cond_signal(&p_cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_lock);
    }
}
```